# flutter emulator is too slow on Corei7

Tags: android-studio, flutter, cpu, intel

My cpu support EPT + UG features, but i get this error and can't load android emulator

Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
[image: my cpu support VT]

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is seems because of lower RAM. 
Checkout these references:
https://androidforums.com/threads/android-studio-emulator-problem.1258457/ 
https://bgjir.wordpress.com/2018/07/06/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine/ 
https://bgjir.wordpress.com/2018/07/06/warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine/ 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122879698